# Finding endpoints or gaps in linestring?

Tags: arcpy, geometry, fme-form, algorithm, linestring

I have a set of features of type `linestring`. I'm trying to polygonise the linestrings and assumed that they were closed (naive me :) ). Of course some were not closed and I'm trying to locate the gaps or the endpoints of the individual linestrings, so I can close them manually.

How can I locate the gap in or endpoints of an open linestring?

*Available software: QGIS, FME, OpenJump, (ArcMap).*

Comment: I found that the Sextante toolbox in OpenJump has the *Extract endports of lines* method. It does the trick, but OpenJump runs out of memory all the time, which is very annoying. I remember something about QGIS having the Sextante toolbox, but I could not find it.

Comment: (FME solution) Do you create polygon from one linestring or group of linetrings ? If from one then use Coordinate Extractor from index -1 and 0 then create line from it and pass original and new line to creator, if from group of linestring use linejoiner and use first method to created linestring.

Answer (score 0):

I used the "Multipart to singlepart"-tool and then selected each feature in the attributes table to find the gap.

Comment: I think the OP wants some kind of algorithm (the tags indicate it) and not "how-to" steps

Answer (score 0):

You can identify lines with gaps between endpoints using [arcpy Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Geometry/018z00000070000000/) objects (v10.1+). The following returns the distance between endpoints:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("LINES_FC", "SHAPE@") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print arcpy.PointGeometry(row[0].firstPoint).distanceTo(arcpy.PointGeometry(row[0].lastPoint))
```

Of course, additional code may be used to select, zoom to, close, etc. those lines identified as  not closed.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do this in FME come to mind:

You can pass the features into an **[AreaBuilder](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/areabuilder.htm)** transformer.  As long as snapping is not enabled, then all features that come out of the Area port will be polygons.  Everything else will not. If you enable end point snapping, it will automatically close the polygons if they are within a tolerance you choose.

[image]

Another way to do it is to automatically close the lines using a **[LineCloser](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/linecloser.htm)**. However, the documentation states to

> Use this transformer with care: the result may self-intersect.

You can also use a **[ClosedCurveFilter](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/closedcurvefilter.htm)** transformer. The documentation states:

> Checks if curves form closed loops. Curves include lines, arcs, and
>   paths. This transformer can also check aggregates of curves. An
>   aggregate is closed if all of its elements are closed. If any element
>   of an aggregate is not a curve, the aggregate is rejected.

There are other methods you could try.  You can test that the start and end coordinates are equal using a few methods such as a [**Tester**](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/tester.htm), **[GeometryCoercer](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/geometrycoercer.htm)** or even a **[PythonCaller](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/pythoncaller.htm)**.